# PHP crashes on echo

Tags: php, buffer

I am debugging an open source PHP software (not a free one) for a client of mine.
It's a cashier software.
They have an issue with a document containing 748 lines.
When trying to display the document, PHP crashes and the user have to wait for the timeout.

It crashes on that echo (not the affichageUneLigne function, but really on the echo):

```
while ($r_sql = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo affichageUneLigne($conn_mag, $r_sql, $typePRIX, $articleTEMPS, $clienDe, $caissier, $themeCAISSE, $provenance);

    print '<div id="clearer"></div>';

    $cptLIGNE++;
}
```

When I do that:

```
while ($r_sql = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($r_sql['DL_Ligne'] < 6360000){
        echo affichageUneLigne($conn_mag, $r_sql, $typePRIX, $articleTEMPS, $clienDe, $caissier, $themeCAISSE, $provenance);

        print '<div id="clearer"></div>';

        $cptLIGNE++;
    }
}
```

or that:

```
while ($r_sql = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($r_sql['DL_Ligne'] >= 6360000){
        echo affichageUneLigne($conn_mag, $r_sql, $typePRIX, $articleTEMPS, $clienDe, $caissier, $themeCAISSE, $provenance);

        print '<div id="clearer"></div>';

        $cptLIGNE++;
    }
}
```

It works. (Knowing that DL_Ligne is the line number with a step of 1000.)

I tought of a buffer length problem, but ob_flush before that line doesn't solve it, nor does it by increasing the memory_limit parameter.

PS: Do not ask me chy the developpers of this software have mixed echo and print, it's like that everywhere in the code...

Comment: So, read error logs, find the error message.

Comment: If you are debugging, you should include actual error messages here. If you are not displaying those, how do you even know where its crashing?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). `mysql_` may account for your crash.

Comment: whats the `affichageUneLigne` function ?

Comment: Have you implemented the suggestion of @AbraCadaver? Any errors displayed on screen? P.S: Put the suggested code on top of your php page, right after any `session_start()` (if any).

Comment: Nothing in the error logs... Logging the errors stream is the first thing I did.

Comment: Obsidian, it's not my code.
I replace mysql_ functions in that software by PDO module by module.

Comment: I repeat my question from above... No errors on screen? Also, do you have logging activated at all?

Comment: @aendeerei No errors on screen not in the logs either. Because it's ajax request I use that lines
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', PATH_LOGS . DS . "php-error.log"); (DS is for DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you do something like this?

```
<?php 

$outputArray = [];

while ($r_sql = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $outputArray[] = affichageUneLigne($conn_mag, $r_sql, $typePRIX, $articleTEMPS, $clienDe, $caissier, $themeCAISSE, $provenance);

    $cptLIGNE++;
}

$outputString = implode('<div id="clearer"></div>', $outputArray);

echo $outputString . '<div id="clearer"></div>';
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it works! ^^
For the not unique id, I know that. I repeat, I'm not the original developper of that code. I work with the editor of that 12-year old software to correct the code.

Comment: @T'lash About id's: I knew that and I already trusted your skills. I just wanted to point out something that even the most experienced programmer can visually miss. About printing inside a while loop: printing is a resource eater. Doing a print on each iteration step, where other potentially "hard" operations are executed, is not quite an elegant solution. Imho, fetching data into an array and printing once afterwords is better.

Comment: @T'lash The same is applicable for db operations: better fetch all data into an array and print afterwards by iterating through it, than feching and printing each record at the same time... P.S: I'm glad it worked. Good luck!